# Excel Toggle Buttons Turning into Pictures

Tags: excel, activex

I have a spreadsheet with Toggle Buttons that will hide or show specific columns - in this case its data for a month.  Click the button, columns are automatically hidden for the user. Click the button again, the columns appear. On February 1, they click the "show February" button to display all the relevant columns for that month.

[image]

A couple of users over the last two years have had the buttons mysteriously turn into an picture. I saw picture because when I click on the button, the PICTURE TOOLS tab appears in the ribbon. This happens to maybe 3 of our 20ish users, but its consistent every month.

To fix it, I just delete and replace the Toggle buttons and the VBA code. It works fine when sent back, but at some point in the month, something triggers this again.

Has anyone ever experienced a user-error that turns Toggle Buttons into images? Perhaps something with ActiveX?

Comment: Yes, it's caused by different versions of the MSForms library (usually due to updates). It's one of the common ActiveX issues.

Comment: any thoughts on how to rectify?

Comment: My first suggestion would be to not use activex controls. There isn't a Form togglebutton, but you could use Optionbuttons instead for example.